# Postmessage not working

Tags: javascript, postmessage

I would like to send message from one domain to another. For this purpose am using **postMessage**. I have a code which seems to be good but still it is not able to send message. Have gone through various related post but no use.

Even on same domain it is not working.

It would be very helpful if anyone could point out what's wrong with code. Thanks

**Main Page:**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <iframe src="http://localhost/sandbox/test/test2.html"></iframe>
    <script>
        window.addEventListener( "message",
          function (e) {
                if(e.origin !== 'http://localhost/sandbox/test/test2.html'){ return; } 
                alert(e.data);
          },
          false);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Iframe content:**

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <script>
            top.postMessage('hello', 'http://localhost/sandbox/test/test.html');
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do some basic debugging to find out where the problem is.

Your function starts with an `if` test, but you don't seem to have determined if the problem is that the `if` isn't being entered or if the function isn't being called at all.

Put a `console.log()` statement in there to find out.

Test what the value of `e.origin` is.

You should find that it is `http://localhost` (which doesn't match what you are testing for). [Origins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin) do not include the path segement.

That is why your test is failing.

Comment: Thanks Working! ya, I was putting complete url.

Comment: This seems to be working well for same domain but when Main page is localhost and iframe page is some website, it stores message in cache and returns this cached message every time instead of actual message. Is there any way to bypass this?

Comment: I shouldn't stop the *message* in the cache. More likely the entire HTTP response for the request for the document loaded into the iframe is cached. The normal cache control HTTP headers will apply.